# How to get alerts in teams and email when a pipeline fails in ADF in monitor alerts

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to get alerts in teams and email when a pipeline fails in ADF in monitor alerts.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: please what you have tried so far and error you are facing any

Comment: I have tried in alerts and monitor created an alerts but there we have only email notification we dnt find teams alert

Comment: We need teams alert if a pipeline fails ...we have a webhook and web activity to achieve it through pipeline .....but we need to achieve it through alerts without creating a pipeline....so please suggest if there is any solution for that

Comment: Have you tried this article? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/how-to-send-notifications-to-teams.md

Comment: Yes Ratheesh ,we have tried but there we have to create a pipeline but the same scenario we want to achieve it with out pipeline  through alerts and monitor is that possible??

Comment: Ratheesh , that approach we are able to see the response but the body is not sending we can see blank.

Comment: Can you please suggest on this

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your time we have tried it we can able to send to email but we need teams notification.

Comment: Have you considered set an email notifcation to an integratio user and then redirect automatically the email in the Teams Channel? Something like here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-an-email-to-microsoft-teams-from-outlook-108fc274-1e64-4ea1-90bb-51c6c7f267e3 It may do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you the following tutorial to set up alerts in your Azure Data Factory.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-alerts-to-proactively-monitor-your-data-factory-pipelines/

[image]

If you click New Alert Rule, you can create different alerts depending on the event and the severity level.

[image]

There are several different option to be notified

[image]

EDIT:

Regarding the teams notifications, here is a tutorial about how to set up a notifications channel (creating a pipeline).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-notifications-to-teams?tabs=data-factory

Looking the MS docs, do not seem to have a plug and play integration as emails or sms...

Answer (score 0):

In alert rule actions there is no direct way, but you can **Customize alert notifications by using Logic Apps in alert's action group.**

You need to [create a logic app the send message in group chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-logic-apps?tabs=send-teams-message) or in a channel

1. In the  **Logic Apps Designer**  page, select  **When a HTTP request is received**.
2. Paste the common alert schema into the  **Request Body JSON Schema**  field from the following JSON:

   [image]

JSON Sample:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "schemaId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "essentials": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "alertId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertRule": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "severity": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "signalType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "monitorCondition": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "monitoringService": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertTargetIDs": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "configurationItems": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "originAlertId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "firedDateTime": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "resolvedDateTime": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "essentialsVersion": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertContextVersion": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "alertContext": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "properties": {},
                        "conditionType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "condition": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "windowSize": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "allOf": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "metricName": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "metricNamespace": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "operator": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "threshold": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "timeAggregation": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "dimensions": {
                                                "type": "array",
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "object",
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "name": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "value": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "required": [
                                                        "name",
                                                        "value"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "metricValue": {
                                                "type": "integer"
                                            },
                                            "webTestName": {}
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "windowStartTime": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "windowEndTime": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "customProperties": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Then click on (+) sign below to add another action In the search field, search for  **Microsoft Teams**.
4. Select  **Microsoft Teams**. Select  **Post message in a chat or channel**  from the list of actions and Sign in to Teams when you're prompted to create a connection.
5. Select  **User**  from the  **Post as**  dropdown. Select  **Group chat**  from the  **Post in**  dropdown.
6. Create the message text in the  **Message**  field by entering static text and including content taken from the alert payload by choosing fields from the  **Dynamic content**  list. For example:

   - **name:**
     [image]
7. Select  **Save**. You've created a logic app that sends a Teams message to the specified group, with details from the alert that triggered it.

The next step is to create an action group to trigger your logic app.

1. Go to the  **Azure Monitor**  page and select  **Alerts**  from the pane on the left.
2. Select  **Action groups**  >  **Create**.
3. Select values for  **Subscription**,  **Resource group**, and  **Region**.
4. Enter a name for  **Action group name**  and  **Display name**.

[image]

5. Select the  **Actions**  tab.
6. On the  **Actions**  tab under  **Action type**, select  **Logic App**.
7. In the  **Logic App**  section, select your logic app from the dropdown.
8. Set  **Enable common alert schema**  to  **Yes**. If you select  **No**, the alert type determines which alert schema is used. For more information about alert schemas
9. Select  **OK**.
10. Enter a name in the  **Name**  field.

[image]

11. Select  **Review + create**  >  **Create**.

**Now add this action group in your alert rule you will get teams notification whel alert rule is triggered.**

**Output:**

[image]